# how to disable android touchscreen in a background service

Tags: android, background

I want to turn off touches on the screen just for 1 or 2 seconds and then turn on. How to do this with a background service as an infinite loop? For instance, if you touch once you cannot touch again in 2 seconds in anywhere on the screen and then keep doing same thing for every touches (not include back, menu or home buttons).

Note: I am using [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for background progress.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've alread done?

Answer (score 0):

You might could do it this way. Disable all views (you can iterate over all children of your root layout) and enable them after two seconds.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    final Button btnDisable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisable);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    btnDisable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            root.setEnabled(false);
            btnDisable.setEnabled(false);
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //enable your views after 2 seconds
                    root.setEnabled(true);
                    btnDisable.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the xml inside of a RelativeLayout with the id `activity_main`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<Button
    android:text="disable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnDisable"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment but I want to manage all touches with a background service, even if user open another application when app still running in background.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable touch only in your app consider [bounding](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) service and communicate with your `Activity` and override `MotionEvent` related methods, e.g.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // your code goes here if needed
    return true; //disabled touching in whole activity
}
```

if you want to disable touching in whole system then this is obvoiusly impossible, because is highly unsecure for user...

Comment: Not only in my app. I want to disable temprorarily even when user open another apps my app still should work on background. Is this possible?

Comment: like I wrote - highly unsecure for user, not possible with "usual" app. if you just want to achieve "background working" you may use `Service` instead of doing everything in UI thread of `Activity`, it will stay in background and do its job even when `Activity` go to the background. locking touching everywhere is very bad idea for catching some time only for your app